# Associating menu items with pages in MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I'm currently converting an existing custom-built content management system from using MySQL to MongoDB. The CMS has pages which have a title and body content, stored in a table called `pages`.

The CMS also has multiple menus which can be edited by the web site administrators, all stored in a table called `menus`. Each has a unique ID and links within it, stored in a table called `menu_links`.

In `menu_links`, there is a column that indicates whether the menu link is to an page or a URL and a column that holds the ID of the page it links to, or `NULL` if it a URL. This is to prevent menu URLs breaking should the page's URL change.

All I can see to find for MongoDB is for embedding documents within one-another which would end up with duplicated data for menus and a very difficult system to manage. Would it be appropriate to link a page's ID to the menu item?

Comment: MongoDB is not relational database, so you have to unnormalise data.
NoSQL it's not good choice if you have many relations
From what i understood, you can combine `menus` and `menu_links` tables

Comment: @AdamW. I understand that and will be doing but I need to know how to indicate which link a page is related to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that was what you meant

Page

```
{
    _id: 111,
    // other fields
    url: "url/to/page/111"
}
```

Menu

```
{
    _id: 1,
    elements: [
        {page_id: 111, url: "url/to/page/111"},
        {page_id: 222, url: "url/to/page/222"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: That works - what's the best way to fetch the page it relates to from there? Can I use `lookup`?